# cinnamon-settings not working: ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSConnection'

Tags: linux-mint, python, cinnamon

I am running Linux mint and since some time, my cinnamon settings apps no longer work [e.g. Display, Backgrounds, etc]. Running it in a terminal I found the following issue.

```
$ cinnamon-settings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/cinnamon-settings.py", 
  line 724, in <module>
window = MainWindow()
  File "/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/cinnamon-settings.py", 
line 305, in __init__
for module in modules:
  File "/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/modules/cs_applets.py", 
line 4, in <module>
    from ExtensionCore import ManageSpicesPage, DownloadSpicesPage
  File "/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/bin/ExtensionCore.py", 
line 19, in <module>
    from Spices import Spice_Harvester, ThreadedTaskManager
  File "/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/bin/Spices.py", line 23, in <module>
from http.client import HTTPSConnection
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSConnection'
```

I have tried reinstalling python, but that did not change anything. I read cinnamon now uses Python 3, and it seems the code could be run by the default python2 version. However, not clear how to fix this?

Comment: I had the very same problem after upgrading to Mint 19, turned out I had stray libssl and libcrypto libraries in /usr/local/lib left over from working around Qt 5.12 libssl version issues in Mint 18.

Comment: Indeed. I found the same issue (after a long search). I have added this as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had libssl.so.1.1 (and libcrypto.so.1.1) in /usr/local/lib. This clashed with the libssl.so.1.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

removing the shared objects in /usr/local/lib and keeping

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem, it started after a failed update.
The culprit was a libssl package conflict.

Fixing package dependencies worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: I tried sudo apt-get -f install libssl-dev (and variations) but no luck. How can I detect the conflicts such that I can check the right package?